# Resources not loaded from cache

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, caching, cache-control

I try to cache some file from my web application. Currently I use grunt to put version on my ressources : myFile.js? < version >

But in Chrome console, I can see that it is not loaded from cache :

[image]

This is my index.html :

```
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <!-- Infos -->
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="FrontEnd/Ressources/img/logo-app.png" />
    <link rel="shorcut" sizes="192x192" href="Ressources/img/logo-app.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="FrontEnd/Ressources/img/logo-app.png" />

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="FrontEnd/Ressources/js/XXXX.min.js?ver=@@XXXX-source-version"></script>
    <script src="FrontEnd/config.js?ver=@@XXXX-source-version"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="FrontEnd/Ressources/css/XXXX.min.css?ver=@@XXXX-source-version" />
</head>
```

How can I reduce loading time and is it loading from cache ( maybe like this file ) ?

[image]

Comment: That looks rather like a timestamp than a “real” version number. Have you verified this value _stays the same_ across subsequent requests for the page that embeds those resources?

Comment: Yes it's a timestamp value, but this value is fix each time I build my project. I'm testing in a pre-prod environment. I'm sure this value remains.

Comment: Check the HTTP response headers. Maybe your underlying server is not set up properly to generate the necessary headers in the first place? (I’m thinking stuff like Last-Modified, ETag, Expires, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in Google that when the dev tools are open the cache is disabled. Maybe you've have this checked?
[image: dev tools window]

The -version suffix could be the cullprit if that number is changed for each request it won't be cached. Thats the sole purpose of that suffix: to make the url unique and disallow loading an outdated version from cache. If it is the same, it should be cached.

Personally I check the caching of things on a non-developer machine or spin up a non-tweaked VM. That way I am sure it is a more normal environment eg one that isn't tweaked to cache as little as possible.

Comment: The "disble cache" check box isn't check and i'm sure the -version suffix still the same

Comment: @Alexandre: maybe a dumb question, but how are you testing this? how are you refreshing the page? What happens when you let the page load, refresh a couple of times with the button in the toolbar? What setup do you use btw? (client+server)

Comment: I use chrome and refresh my page with "CTRL+F5". My website is on WIN SRV 2012 R2 and IIS